# Error when connect database transient failure in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2022, npgsql

I am using VS2022 and I am trying to run a Linq query agaisnt an AWS hosted Postgres database and I receive the next error:

```
An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure
```

I tried to change my UnitOfWork code from:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(ApplicationSettings.Database.ConnectionString, options =>
                {
                    options.CommandTimeout(ApplicationSettings.Database.CommandTimeout);
                    options.SetPostgresVersion(Version.Parse(ApplicationSettings.Database.Version));
                });
        }
```

To:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(ApplicationSettings.Database.ConnectionString, options =>
                {
                    options.CommandTimeout(ApplicationSettings.Database.CommandTimeout);
                    options.SetPostgresVersion(Version.Parse(ApplicationSettings.Database.Version));
                    options.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
                });
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```

In this case, I received the next error:

```
The maximum number of retries (5) was exceeded while executing database operations with 'NpgsqlRetryingExecutionStrategy
```

**Trace**

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
  Source=Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
  StackTrace:
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at UKIAwardsShared.DataLayer.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1 predicate) in C:\Projects\UKI\UKIAwards\.UKIAwardsShared\UKIAwardsShared\DataLayer\Repository.cs:line 35
   at UKIAwardsFaqs.Services.FaqsService.FaqsService.HasPermission(String enterpriseId) in C:\Projects\UKI\UKIAwards\UKIAwardsFaqs\UKIAwardsFaqs\Services\FaqsService\FaqsService.cs:line 151
   at UKIAwardsFaqs.Services.FaqsService.FaqsService.Get(String countryCode, String enterpriseId, Int32 id) in C:\Projects\UKI\UKIAwards\UKIAwardsFaqs\UKIAwardsFaqs\Services\FaqsService\FaqsService.cs:line 45
   at UKIAwardsFaqs.Controllers.DataController.Get(Int32 id) in C:\Projects\UKI\UKIAwards\UKIAwardsFaqs\UKIAwardsFaqs\Controllers\DataController.cs:line 41
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
NpgsqlException: Exception while connecting

Inner Exception 2:
TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
```

**Details**

```
Internal error in the expression evaluator.
```

From my computer I can connect to this DB via telnet and pga Admin. One colleague has the same problem and another one needs to try to connect by postman a few times before he gets it.

Any hint from where can I start?

Comment: how complex is your linq query - is it having many subqueries and joins ?

Comment: It's not "transition". The word is "transient" in your error message, which basicaly means short-lived and not regular.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran It is just a get with a couple of joins. It is now so much complex

Comment: @jmcilhinney Corrected it

Comment: Then it is likely that, your db is running on development server or some hardware that has lot of issues, or network drops, since the npgsql driver clearly says it as 'transient'.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran At the very beginning it worked and no one changed anythingy. Could be something related with Visual Studio configuration?

Comment: You need to post your full exception details, including the stack trace; that should provide information on exactly what error is occurring.

Comment: @ShayRojansky. Information requested was provided. Many Thanks

Comment: OK, so it seems you're getting a timeout. This could be because your query takes too long; in that case, the timeout would also happen on the same query (or queries), and you need to analyze them, possibly add an index, etc.

Comment: Otherwise this could be some networking issue or similar; the end result is that Npgsql doesn't receive a response within the alotted time, which is 30 seconds by default. You can also change the command timeout via the connection string ([see docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#timeouts-and-keepalive)), but it's a good idea to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: @ShayRojansky. I tried to change the timeout of the connection string, but nothing. All queries fail, even the simplest select ones. On other computers it works properly, I would rule out a network problem. I have seen that in previous versions of Visual Studio, this problem was caused by a bug. Can this be the problem?

Comment: It looks like it's timing out connecting to the database server. It doesn't even seem to get to the command timeout. You mention it works on other computers, can this computer access the database outside of the web app?

Comment: @jessehouwing It is hosted in AWS. I can enter in its adminitration page and see their data. In another computer doesn't work as well.

Comment: The admin page says very little. Can you connect to the PostgreSQL port? Default would be 5432. Try telnetting to it, it should be able to establish a connection. I suspect you'll need to update the firewall rules.

Comment: @jessehouwing Sorry for my ignorance. What is telnetting? How can we do it?

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=use%20telnet%20to%20test%20connection&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-m

Comment: @jessehouwing. checked, there isn´t connection

Comment: Then you're looking at a network problem most likely. Either the local firewall on the machine making the outbound connection, or at the router level from the place you're trying to connect out from (central office network configuration?), But most likely the configuration at the AWS side.

Comment: @jessehouwing Sorry, my mistake. I connect via telnet. I Forgot to open the VPN.

Comment: @jessehouwing . I can connect by PGA admin as well.